Is there a limit below a panel's rating for bonding neutrals and grounds?
I have a 225Amp rated main breaker and panel box.
The neutral and ground bus bars are bonded directly to the neutral main and are full, unfortunately.
We want to add a 50A RV circuit to the panel, and there is an empty threaded hole in the panel where I could add a neutral/ground bus bar expansion to the panel.  In my own home, I have such a setup at the advice of my county inspector, but only with 15/20amp circuits.
Is sending 50A through the skin of the panel also okay, or is there a point at which amperage need a direct connection to the neutral main?

Can you upload pictures of your panel?

To be clear - you probably have ground sharing space on the neutral bar or bars. You can add accessory ground bars and move all the grounds to those bars (maintaining the bond as it's a bonded main panel.) You cannot move neutrals to an accessory ground bar even in a bonded main panel (and typically should not need to.)

Can't say for sure without seeing the panel, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if your neutral and ground bars are being used in a less than optimal way.
Check the instruction label for your panel. If it is missing or faded beyond readability, if you can at least find out the model # or type of panel then it should be possible to get information from the manufacturer.
The key is that instead of one ground or neutral wire per screw, you can often, but not always, put 2 or even 3 ground (but not neutral) wires per screw, depending on the size of the wires and the specifics of the panel.
If your neutral and ground bars are full now with one wire - of any type - per screw, then rearranging grounds to combine them, where allowed by the manufacturer, and moving grounds to the ground bar(s) to free up more room on the neutral bar(s) can often give you enough capacity for your new ground and neutral wires.
However, it is possible that you are truly running out of space. In particular, some panels originally only allowed a small number of half-size/tandem breakers, due to a limit on the total breakers/circuits per panel. As I understand it, that limit has been essentially removed, which allows all spaces in a panel to use half-size/tandem breakers, subject to any actual design limitations (some panels limited with physical things, others just with labels). So it is possible that you have more legitimate breakers/circuits in the panel than originally designed and are truly running out of neutral and ground spaces. In that case, you can add a ground bar easily in nearly any panel, but neutral bars are a different story altogether. Why? Because neutrals carry large amounts of current in normal usage, and grounds don't.

Is it any common for panels to permit two neutral wires per screw? I thought that that trick only worked for grounds (where allowed at all). It feels like two neutrals sharing a screw is quite the recipe for all sorts of imperfect connections (tasked with carrying full working current, with hilarious consequences) and potentially an easy-to-miss loose neutral (also an exciting situation, especially on MWBCs).

@TooTea -- it only works for grounds

@TooTea Emphasis added.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Oh, sorry, I misread that paragraph as talking about both grounds and neutrals.

Simply tacking the 50A neutral & ground onto a threaded hole in the panel box is not good. It is very unlikely that the panel's instructions on the label allow this, meaning that code (assuming USA's NEC, but others may be the same) won't like it, since code requires using an item according to its instructions.
Also, putting neutral current on ground devices is not allowed, which happens when the box hole is used for neutral connections.
Your insurance company will definitely have an opinion when adjusting a claim after the fire, and they'll probably side with the code requirements.
Getting some compatible ground and neutral bars for your panel per the panel manufacturer's label, literature, or website would be the safest way. They have designed their add-on neutral & ground bars to successfully handle the currents that the panel is built for.
